# html/css: Change content of animated flexbox-element on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a row of four boxes with large, single letters inside, they are set up using `flexbox` to span the entire width of the page. The boxes slightly rotate on hover.

I would like the content of a box to  change on hover as well, i.e. I would like the `background-color` to shift to black and display a `paragraph` of smaller text inside the box when hovering over the respective box. I cannot figure out to do so. First, I was thinking of "hiding" boxes with the desired change appearance by setting their `display: none` and then change it to `inline` once the user hovers of the respective white box. However, I cannot manage to properly hide a box as it somehow messes with the `flexbox` and also the invisble box would not properly rotate like its white counterpart.

Any ideas how I can achieve the changing content and appearance of the white boxes on hover? Here's a jsfiddle of the current setup of the boxes:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.banner {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 13rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: default;
}

.rotate-right {
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.rotate-left {
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.rotate-right:hover {
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}

.rotate-left:hover {
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<!-- BANNER/TILES ON TOP OF PAGE -->

<div class="top" id="top">
  <div>

    <div class="flex row banner">
      <div class="box rotate-right" id="box1">
        <p>
          1
        </p>
      </div>


      <div class="box rotate-left">
        <p>
          2
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-right">
        <p>
          3
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-left">
        <p>
          4
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? Demo is in box 1.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.banner {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 13rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: default;
}

.rotate-right {
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.rotate-left {
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.rotate-right:hover {
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  background: black;
}

.rotate-left:hover {
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  background: black;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  display: none;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.rotate-right:hover p.text,
.rotate-left:hover p.text {
  display: inline-block;
}


.rotate-right:hover p:not([class="text"]),
.rotate-left:hover p:not([class="text"]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- BANNER/TILES ON TOP OF PAGE -->

<div class="top" id="top">
  <div>

    <div class="flex row banner">
      <div class="box rotate-right" id="box1">
        <p>
          1
        </p>
        <p class="text">Text</p>
      </div>


      <div class="box rotate-left">
        <p>
          2
        </p>
        <p class="text">Text</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-right">
        <p>
          3
        </p>
        <p class="text">Text</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box rotate-left">
        <p>
          4
        </p>
        <p class="text">Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should add -> .rotate-right:hover p, .rotate-left:hover p {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}
for color white on hover

Comment: That's define for .text. You can only see the text in full page mode.

Comment: I'm now hiding the number also, so only the text is rendered inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

```
.box:hover {background-color: red;font-size: 25px;}
```

Try this it will be helpful